# using ggplot2 - removing solid black and gray line at bottom of my plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is what my plot looks like

[image: img]

At the bottom of the plot has a dark black line, and below that there is a thick gray line.

Is there a way to remove these lines? And why are they there?

Here is a copy of my code for making this plot if that is helpful:

```
abstract_bing %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = url, y = sentiment)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, fill = "#bc4b51") + #, position = "dodge") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) + 
  labs(title = "", x = "", y = "") +
  theme(text = element_text(color = "#000000"),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#E2E2E2"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "#E2E2E2"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#F6F6F6"))
```

Edit: Here is an example of what the data in the `abstract_bing` df looks like:

There are 9957 rows total

```
  url                                   negative positive sentiment
  <chr>                                    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3382~        0        5         5
2 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3462~        2        3         1
3 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3469~        2        7         5
4 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3470~        4        1        -3
5 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3479~        1        3         2
6 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3485~        7        3        -4
```

Essentially I am using `x = url` to have a bar for each unique `url` that shows its respective `sentiment` value.

Comment: hi there.. might you show us what the data look like?  What do the values `url` that you place in `x` in the `mapping`??  Is that some type of character/factor?

Comment: The issue is most likely that you map 9957 different (?) categories on the x axis. Hence, the dark black line are simply 9957 tick marks while your grey line are the 9957 labels. As a simple example of this issue check `ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = runif(1000)), aes(factor(x), y)) + geom_col()`

Comment: Adding on to what @stefan said, what did you expect the x-axis to look like with all those strings? Or were you trying to do something else with the data before plotting it?

Comment: @camille So the red "bars" was my goal and it is there but the black line and gray line were unexpected and I did not know how they appeared.

Comment: Right, the black & gray lines are your text all blurred together. But what did you expect to have happen when you put almost 10,000 long strings of text as labels of a discrete axis? What do you want that to look like? Even just using the 6 rows of example data and your plotting code, the labels on the x-axis are pretty much illegible

Comment: @camille Yes, I was confused as I did not want the text there, the text does not serve a purpose for me, so seeing my first plot come out I did not think it was text as it just looked like a line.  So now that I know what it was, and I can remove them. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines where tick marks and labels, but because there where so many on top of each other, they appeared as lines. Removing both the x axis text, and the x axis ticks as shown below solved this issue.

```
plot +
   theme(
   axis.text.x = element_blank(),
   axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
   )
```

**Thank you everyone for your help!**